# Convert into am / pm in Impala

Tags: cloudera, impala

Like in a similar query on this forum I need, but I need it to work in Impala:
[image]

In a workaround my colleague and myself attempted the following:

```
-- combine start date and time into a datetime
-- impala can't handle am/pm so need to look for pm indicator and add 12 hours
-- and then subtract 12 hours if it's 12:xx am or pm
 ================

t1.appt_time,
hours_add(
      to_timestamp(concat(to_date(t1.appt_date),' ',t1.appt_time),'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm'),
      12*decode(lower(strright(t1.appt_time,2)),"pm",1,0) - 
      12*decode(strleft(t1.appt_time,2),'12',1,0)
    ) as appt_datetime,
```

t1. ...

=========
Has anybody an easier and more elegant approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround is valid, Impala does currently support AM/PM formatting for dates. There are a few open issues related

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-3381
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-5237
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2262